# How to enumerate list in ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have this structure:

```
addresses:
 - 192.168.1.1
 - 192.168.2.2
 - 192.168.3.3
```

I need to process them in the task:

```
- tasks:
      - name: Iterating
      - template: src=template.j2 dest=/etc/addresses/{{index}}.conf
        with_items: addresses
```

But I can't find any way to fill index variable (or any other similar trick).

Note: I know about indexes inside j2 templates, but I'm talking about tasks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`with_indexed_items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-a-list-with-an-index), another Ansible standard loop.

```
- tasks:
  - name: Iterating
    template: src=template.j2 dest=/etc/addresses/{{ item.0 }}.conf
    with_indexed_items: addresses
```

The address item can be accessed in the template as `{{ item.1 }}`